# Izpack Field Validator

Tags: izpack

I am configuring a field validator for a Linux install but none of the field validators appear to be working. Here is an example taken from the official izpack documentation which I have copy and pasted into my userInputSpec.xml file for testing, however to no avail:

```
<field type="text" variable="ora.db">
<spec txt="SID:" id="text.oraclesettings.sid" size="3" set=""/>
<validator class="com.izforge.izpack.panels.userinput.validator.NotEmptyValidator" txt="Invalid oracle SID!" id="text.oraclesettings.error.sid" />
</field>
```

The xml file is valid because the UI is configured correctly according to its definition. Aside from this stanza defining a validator for a particular field, there is no other configuration required, so I am not sure why it is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: this seems to be broken again in version 5.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem was a bug in the version of izpack I was using (5.0.0), and that it was fixed in 5.0.3, and I have tested it successfully.